# Unable to get the REST Data Services option in SQL Developer after ORDS installation

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-ords

I've done a standalone installation of ORDS for experimental purposes (just HTTP) and REST enabled a schema via the command line:

```
ORDS.ENABLE_SCHEMA(p_enabled => TRUE,
                   p_schema => 'name_of_schema_existing',
                   p_url_mapping_type => 'BASE_PATH',
                   p_url_mapping_pattern => 'hr',
                   p_auto_rest_auth => FALSE);

commit;
```

This ran completed successfully but when I launch SQL Developer and right-click on that schema, I don't get the 'Rest Services' option that I see in various documentations/videos:

[image]

Could anyone help to see why I wouldn't have the above option for my REST enabled schema? I'm running SQL Developer version Version 4.0.3.16.

Thanks so much in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade your SQL Developer.

That would be 22.2 for current version.

[image]

And once your have ORDS running with your schema enabled, you can login to SQL Developer Web and use that for your REST Development.

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much, I didn't know my current version of SQL Developer simply didn't come with the option. I'll ask IT for an upgrade today and check again. :)

Comment: For reference 4.0.3 was released in 2014.

Comment: I've talked to IT today and was told that the latest approved version at our corporation is SQL Developer 19.2 with embedded JDK; would that not have the REST services either? Thanks again -

Comment: 19.2 will have it

Comment: Thanks so much, I got 19.2 installed today - sorry to keep asking, but I still don't see the option to REST enable a schema upon launch. I tried uninstalling and re-installing ORDS and verified by that ORDS is installed and running (java -jar ords.war serve, can hit the 404 page with http://localhost:8080/ords/). Does the version 19.2 not auto-detect the running of ORDS or is there something else that I may be missing?

Comment: SQLDev doesn't detect if ORDS is running, it detects if ORDS is installed in your database.  We query to see if ords.installed_Version > 3.0.4 AND  that DBMS_UTILITY.NAME_RESOLVE() can find the ORDS public synonym that points to ORDS_METADATA.ORDS plsql package. If those two things aren't true, you wont see the ORDS/REST items on the connection tree.